# How to plot density estimation contours of a model with 20 features?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am following [this sample](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_pdf.html) to do density estimation for the Bayesian Gaussian mixture model below:

```
bgmm = BayesianGaussianMixture(n_components=10, random_state=7, max_iter=5000).fit(data)
```

in which `data` (as a dataframe) includes 20 columns of numeric data.

I can simply plot the model for two features of `bgmm` by

```
x = np.linspace(-20.0, 30.0)
y = np.linspace(-20.0, 40.0)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
XX = np.array([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).T
Z = -bgmm.score_samples(XX)
Z = Z.reshape(X.shape)

CS = plt.contour(
    X, Y, Z, norm=LogNorm(vmin=1.0, vmax=1000.0), levels=np.logspace(0, 3, 10)
)
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, shrink=0.8, extend="both")
plt.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], 0.8)

plt.show()
```

But, how can I plot all the clusters in the form of density contours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to get your data into one big two-column array before fitting, so define a new `X_train` that combines all ten pairs of columns into one big pair of columns.

First, convert `data` into an array:

```
data_array = data.to_numpy()
```

And then reshape into two columns:

```
X_train = np.reshape(data_array, (10*data_array.shape[0], 2))
```

and then call the `mixture.fit` method with that instead of `data`. Then just continue following the sample, using `X_train` as they do (and of course use `bgmm` instead of `clf`).

Comment: I think you meant `X_train = np.reshape(data, (20*data.shape[0],2)).T` which returns this error: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40000 into shape (40000,2)`.

Comment: So, given `X_train = np.reshape(data, (10*data.shape[0],2)).T`, I get this error: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (20000, 2), indices imply (2000, 20)`.

Comment: Yes, `data` has 20 columns.

Comment: Also note that `np.reshape(data_array, (10*data_array.shape[0], 2))` can be written easier as `data_array = data_array.reshape(-1, 2)` where `-1` indicates to numpy to automatically calculate the correct size.